# Is Wifi fast enough for VDI VMware View or Citrix Xen

Tags: wifi, vmware-view, vdi, xendesktop

Looking to deploy View or Xen in my house, have a number of older laptops that aren't very quick running Windows 7.  Figured I'd run them as VDI clients as I've got the server capacity.

They'd be connecting over wifi, they're mainly G or B laptops but I can add a N usb adapter or PCMCIA card if needed, and dedicate a separate wifi router for them.

Answer (score 1):

For graphically simple uses, you should be fine. There might be times you notice that wireless has higher latency than a "typical" wired network. For graphically intense uses, you'll really notice the diminished bandwidth and increased latency.

Answer (score 0):

I run RDP over wireless and WAN connections all the time and it works great.

Vmware View uses the Teradichi "PC over IP" protocol which is totally optimized to make the best of  poor network conditions. So it will behave even better then standard RDP would. If the effective bandwidth is low and latency high, then it will automatically degrade the image quality so that it's still smooth.

Comment: Now how is video playback such as flash and media files like mpg avi etc.

Comment: When I use RDP on my laptop across my G/N network in my house, flash stuff isn't too bad. 

But at a VMWare User Group a couple years ago, I saw VMware View in action and gaming, DVDs, etc were all very smooth. I was blown away.

Check this YouTube video of 4-head thin client with View...
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=APVP0DUu34c